# Binding radio button values in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table of experiments, and for each experiment I need to be able to turn it on or off. I pass in a list of my experiments to my view, and iterate over them to create table rows.

Table row creation:

```
<tr>
    <td>@experiment.ExperimentId</td>
    <td>@experiment.ExperimentName</td>
    <td>@experiment.StartDate</td>

    //radio button code goes here
</tr>
```

I've decided to use the radio button helper to generate the two radio buttons for each experiment.

```
<td>@Html.RadioButton(experiment.ExperimentName, true, false)ON @Html.RadioButton(experiment.ExperimentName, false, false)OFF</td>
```

I've used the 'ExperimentName' as the input name, as I want each set of radio buttons to be in their own group.

My question is, when I submit this form, how should I bind the data to the post model. I'm looking to create something like this in the model

Experiments
ExperimentOne -> *selected radiobutton value*
ExperimentTwo -> *selected radiobutton value*

I'm assuming i'll need to create a Dictionary object, but i'm not sure how to bind the name and the selected value to this. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you persisting the fact that an experiment is on or off? Whatever entity/property you're using for that should be used in your form as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with an enabled/disabled situation, I would recommend using a checkbox over two radio buttons. In either case, your model might look something like this:

```
public class ExperimentsViewModel
{
    // other properties
    public IDictionary<int, bool> ExperimentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

And you would bind to this in your view like so:

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("ExperimentStatus[0]", Model.ExperimentStatus[0]) Enabled</td>
```

The model binder treats dictionaries like an array or a list; use can use indexes (keys in this case) to bind to a value. You can also use a string key instead of an integer.

If you must use radio buttons, your view would look like this:

```
<td>
    @Html.RadioButton("ExperimentStatus[0]", true, Model.ExperimentStatus[0], new {id = "ExperimentStatus_0_ON"})@:ON 
    @Html.RadioButton("ExperimentStatus[0]", false, Model.ExperimentStatus[0], new {id = "ExperimentStatus_0_OFF"})@:OFF
</td>
```

You'll have to manually include the id attributes like this because otherwise the ON and OFF inputs would have the same ids, which is invalid HTML.